# Match lookup value lengths for match with beginning of lookup value

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

In Excel 2013 I have two tables.
The first contains alpha numeric codes that vary in length.
Some examples from first table:

- 12345.12345
- 12346-12345
- 12AB1234
- 123.123
- 23456.123
- A1234567.012
- 01234.12345

The second table contains alpha numeric codes I need to match with the beginning of the codes in the first table. Any numeric codes are currently stored as text.
Some examples from second table:

- 12345
- 12346
- 123
- 23456
- A1234567
- 01234

How do I return a value from a different column in the second table containing any value? And for some context, the return column from the second table contains a description of for the codes.

I did not jet manage to find a solution using vlookup or match.
Also looked at using wildcards, but this only works one way, the wrong way.

Comment: Please provide the formulas you have tried and why they did not produce the desired results.  Please also provide the desired results for each scenario.

Comment: What determines the "beginning" of the values in the first table? Can you please also show the expected output?

Comment: @BruceWayne, The values in the second table determine the beginning in the first table. The output should be a value form a different column in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution, assuming you dont care about letters, is to use a `LEFT(FIND(` with substitution. If letters need to be excluded, then explanation will need to be provided how the format should be presented.

Solution: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","."))-1),A2)`

[image: Example]

This formula will find the first "." or "-" and present all characters prior to. If none are found, then it will display the full ID.

*If letters need to be removed as well, however, it should be noted that the use of some serious substitute nesting, or VBA script will be required.*

Comment: The result is similar to the first formula of yass. I could use the result to "lookup" values in the second table. I will play with this approach a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A1 is the first cell in your column, in B1 write the following:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))),0)-1)
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time (Array Formula)
it will return the first numeric part of your Data
you can copy paste values in column C and compare with the second table

To have the result in Table1 directly in B1 use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH(VALUE(LEFT(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))),0)-1)),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time (Array Formula)
It will return the corresponding number from Table2 (sheet2) if matched or "" empty if no match
Change A1:A4 to correspond all your Numbers in Table2 and keep the $ to fix the references when you drag down the formula

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I used the second formula and modified it to retun a value from a different column. I also modified it to work with named references in a table object. Unfortunately, as I was testing, I discovered I missed some crucial info in my question, your formula only works with numerical values and I need to deal with both numeric and alpha numeric values. I clarified my question.

Comment: What about 12AB1234 do you want to reject it?

Comment: You can use =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$6,MATCH(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","."),1)-1),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6,0)),"") if only values that contain "." or "-" you need